# String index out of range for array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make an array that collects the char from a string and places them backwards onto itself, then returns the word into a String.

When I try to run the code it tells me "String index out of range: -1". I've tried everything and cant figure out where in my code the problem is. Here's the code.

```
public class april{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("What do you want backwards?");
    System.out.println("Your new word is " + reverse(IO.readString()));
  }

  public static String reverse(String original){
    char [] letters = new char [original.length()];
    char [] opp = new char [original.length()];
    char c= 'a';
    char d= 'a';
    String word= " ";
    String opposite= " ";

    for (int x=0;x<original.length();x++){
      c = original.charAt(x);
      d = original.charAt(x);
      letters[x]= c;
      if (x!=0){
        d = original.charAt(-x-1);
        opp[x]=d;
      } else {
        d = original.charAt(-1);
        opp[0]= d; 
      }
      word += letters[x];
      opposite += opp[x];
    }
    return opposite;
  }
}
```

Comment: In java you can't use negative in `original.charAt(-1)`!, the index start from 0 to `string.length() - 1` beside what you want to do exactly, what is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: input would be something like Hello, then each char in input would be put into two arrays. One called letters and one called opp. Letters would look like [H, e, l, l, o] and opp would look like [o,l,l,e,H]. Then the char in opp would be put into a string to finally make "elloH".

Comment: so in one word you want to reverse your string right?

Comment: You can just use `String reversed = new StringBuilder("Hello").reverse().toString();`

Comment: you are starting from -1 here, d = original.charAt(-x-1);, change it to      d = original.charAt(x-1);

Comment: Im doing that because I want it to take the number at the end of the string. I tried changing it to that and im still getting the same error

Comment: I have to use arrays. Im having trouble understanding them so its hard for me to grasp why the code isnt working. The -1 of a string should be the last number, the -2 the second to last and so on. Or at least I think so. I dont really see how im going out of bounds either

Comment: If you have to use arrays you can simplify to : `public static String reverse(String original){

     char [] opp = new char [original.length()];
     int index = 0;
     for (char c : original.toCharArray()){
        opp[original.length()- 1 - index++] = c;
     }
     return Arrays.toString(opp);
 }`

Answer (score 1):

To reverse a string is much simpler. Consider the following:

```
public static String reverse(String original) {
    char[] reverse = new char[original.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length; i++) {
        reverse[i] = original.charAt(original.length() - i - 1);
    }
    return new String(reverse);
}
```

All you need to do is iterate in one direction and take the opposite character in the other at each pass. Notice the -1 because `original.length()` will give you a 1-based index.

Comment: I tried it but i continue to get the same same error

Comment: What was your `original` value?

Comment: original String was 'cookie'

Comment: What happens if you debug `IO.readString()`? I suspect it alters `cookie`.

Comment: try `System.out.println("Your new word is " + reverse("cockie"));`  - it works fine

Comment: Sorry i havent heard of debugging before so I dont have much of an idea. I tried what @c0der recommended, where I say "System.out.println("Your new word is " + reverse("cockie"));" and that failed as well

Comment: with my reverse method?

Comment: @WilliamBurnham method works fine. If something fails its must be from other reason. Test run it [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/r3RTyv2kLu)